# How to index mbtiles to speed up load time?

Tags: qgis, mapbox, maperitive, indexing

I have created a mbtile based on OpenStreetMap data with Maperitive using the command:

```
generate-mbtiles file=Path\filename.mbtiles maxzoom=16
```

Loading the file in QGIS 2.14.0 and zooming takes 15-30 seconds, even if zoomed in at zoomlevel 16.

Is there a method index mbtiles to speed up load time?

Answer (score 1):

Generated mbtiles database doesn't contain any indexes. You can inspect it using DB Browser for SQLite.

To speed up the query you can create unique index for `tiles` table on three columns: `zoom_level`, `tile_column` and `tile_row`.